# Input fields won't stop repopulating with jQuery and setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, settimeout

I am populating the input values in a widget with values that are passed through the URL when the input fields are clicked on. Because the widget takes longer than the rest of the page to load, I use setTimeout() with jQuery to accomplish this:

```
var email = getUrlParameter('email');
console.log(email);

var description = getUrlParameter('description');
console.log(description);

// Contents of the two input fields I wish to populate
var first = $('#ticketSubmissionForm').contents().find('input[name="email"]').val();
var second = $('#ticketSubmissionForm').contents().find('textarea[name="description"]').val();
console.log(first);
console.log(second);

var timerone, timertwo;

timerone = setTimeout(function(){
    $('#ticketSubmissionForm').contents().find('label.Form-fieldContainer.u-block').click(function(){
        if (!first) {
            var change = $('#ticketSubmissionForm').contents().find('input[name="email"]').val(email);
            console.log(change);
            clearTimeout(timerone);
        }
    });
}, 4000);

timertwo = setTimeout(function(){
    $('#ticketSubmissionForm').contents().find('textarea[name="description"]').click(function(){
        if (!second){
             var change2 = $('#ticketSubmissionForm').contents().find('textarea[name="description"]').val(description);
             console.log(change2);
             clearTimeout(timertwo);
        }
    });
}, 4000);
```

The input fields do populate properly, the problem is that anytime anywhere else is clicked, or if the field is re-clicked, the data is overwritten again, erasing anything that may have been added to the field.

I tried to irradicate this problem by saying `clearTimeout(timerone)` and `clearTimeout(timertwo)` whenever the condition is satisfied, but this does not change anything.

Can anyone see what my issue is? I wish to stop populating the field after the first clicks fill the fields

Comment: Please add some html of your code

Comment: I do not have access to the widget code, I only have access to the html elements. The selectors using jQuery are correct

Comment: you're missed to reinit `first ` and `second` variables

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean by that

Comment: Of course. `reinit ` I mean change inited value.

Comment: In setTimeout you add click handler. And in if statement you check value of one setted vatiables which is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missed to reinit `first` and `second` variables:

```
var email = getUrlParameter('email');
console.log(email);

var description = getUrlParameter('description');
console.log(description);

// Contents of the two input fields I wish to populate
var first = $('#ticketSubmissionForm').contents().find('input[name="email"]').val();
var second = $('#ticketSubmissionForm').contents().find('textarea[name="description"]').val();
console.log(first);
console.log(second);

setTimeout(function(){
        $('#ticketSubmissionForm').contents().find('label.Form-fieldContainer.u-block').click(function(){
            if (!first) {
                var change = $('#ticketSubmissionForm').contents().find('input[name="email"]').val(email);
                console.log(change);
                first = email;
            }
        });
        $('#ticketSubmissionForm').contents().find('textarea[name="description"]').click(function(){
            if (!second){
                 var change2 = $('#ticketSubmissionForm').contents().find('textarea[name="description"]').val(description);
                 console.log(change2);
                 second = description;
            }
        });
}, 4000);
```

Comment: This is correct, thank you. However, the issue I am now having is that once the cursor leaves those input fields, the autofilled data goes away

Answer (score 0):

you can use $(document).ready() if you want to ensure that the dom is ready.

```js
 var email = 'email';//getUrlParameter('email');
 var description = 'description';//getUrlParameter('description');

 // Contents of the two input fields I wish to populate
 var first = $('#ticketSubmissionForm').find('input[name="email"]').val();
 var second = $('#ticketSubmissionForm').find('textarea[name="description"]').val();

 $(document).ready(function() { // or just $(function() {...});
  $('#ticketSubmissionForm').find('label.Form-fieldContainer.u-block').click(function(){
   if (!first) {
    $('#ticketSubmissionForm').find('input[name="email"]').val(email);
                first = email;
   }
  });
  $('#ticketSubmissionForm').find('textarea[name="description"]').click(function(){
   if (!second){
     $('#ticketSubmissionForm').find('textarea[name="description"]').val(description);
                second = description;
   }
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="ticketSubmissionForm">
<label class="Form-fieldContainer u-block">label</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" />
  <textarea name="description"></textarea>
</form>
```

btw the `.content()` calls are not necessary since you are not selecting text-nodes or comments. you cann use `.find()` directly instead.

alternative to changing the first and second value you can also use the jquery `.one()` method, which removes the eventhandler after the first call

```js
var email = 'email'; //getUrlParameter('email');
var description = 'desription'; //getUrlParameter('description');

// Contents of the two input fields I wish to populate
var first = $('#ticketSubmissionForm').find('input[name="email"]').val();
var second = $('#ticketSubmissionForm').find('textarea[name="description"]').val();

$(document).ready(function() { // or just $(function() {...});
  $('#ticketSubmissionForm').find('label.Form-fieldContainer.u-block').one('click', function(){
    if (!first) {
      $('#ticketSubmissionForm').find('input[name="email"]').val(email);
    }
  });
  $('#ticketSubmissionForm').find('textarea[name="description"]').one('click', function(){
    if (!second){
       $('#ticketSubmissionForm').find('textarea[name="description"]').val(description);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="ticketSubmissionForm">
<label class="Form-fieldContainer u-block">label</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" />
  <textarea name="description"></textarea>
</form>
```